# Search on a ArrayList

Tags: java, search, arraylist, contains

Hello im trying to find a specific element on ArrayList whit various elements, i tried multiple things, but i think this ways is the best. But the Problem is when the program do the IF condition
it seems that he cant recognize the thing i want to search.

Heres the file that i want to search :

```
7dD5DEzjhofoItSG7QwVoY @ ['Frank Sinatra']
5TnAnWRXDM6awfvAveK91N @ ['Mountain John']
5tNhreO6L8kfvQSqPjuGUg @ ['Rammstein']
4Cna7QxOOTNnylVHLtShCi @ ['Madonna']
2Sy1r4fGfq4Lslfc0gHkbk @ "['La Sonora Matancera', 'Carlos Argentino']"
3uXp4hZmCnEmVjffupKCiT @ ['Supertramp']
```

Heres my code :

```
public static void ADD_TAGS(ArrayList<Song> artistaMusica,String Artista,String NewTag){
        
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

       // System.out.println("O array contem :" + artistaMusica);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < artistaMusica.size() ; i++) {


            if  (Artista == artistaMusica.get(i).getnomeArtista()) {

                System.out.println("Artista procurado :" + Artista );

            }
        }


        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("(took "+(end-start)+" ms)\n");

    }
```

Comment: What is Artista?

Comment: Its the Artist that i want to search

Comment: What is the question? Did you manage to parse artists?

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings, so in your if statement you should use Artista.equals(artistaMusica.get(i).getnomeArtista()

Answer (score 0):

Probably better with equals method like that:

```
for (Song actual: artistaMusica) {
        if (actual.getnomeArtista().equals("What u want")) {
            System.out.println(actual);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gave me the same result, it does not print the value on the variable.